# Why is my kotlin hash set not adding elements

Tags: kotlin, interface, hashset

I am new to kotlin and I want to make an abstract/open class or interface, something that can be implemented by other classes. Let's call it `Test`. Now `Test` needs to have a HashSet (the docs say it requires less memory than a normal set) that every derived class will implement and fill with its own values.

```kotlin
interface Test {
    val players: HashSet<String>
}
class Supa: Test {
    override val players = hashSetOf<String>()
    fun later() {
        players.add("new player")
    }
}
fun main() {
    Supa().later()
    println(Supa().players)
    
}
```

The above will output `[]`. It seems that for some reason `players` doesn't get updated. After playing around in the kotlin playground I found out that if I print `players` from inside `later()` it will show the added element. Maybe it creates a new instance of player that exists in the scope of the function?? Could someone please show me how I can make an abstract hashSet that the derived class can override and fill with values that stay in the set?

Comment: You're creating an instance of `Supa` and calling `later()` on it, but then you create *another* one and access `players` on **that**. Since you never called `later()` on the second one, there's nothing in its set. If you want that set shared among *all the instances of that class* (like a static property) you need to put it in a companion object

Comment: So this means that I have to make both later() and players static inside supa with a companion object. But then I would not be able to implement  Test. Is there a way to do this without having to copy the HashSet(in my code it is not only the HashSet) for every class?

Comment: I think I found a way
<https://pl.kotl.in/G5NYOUsmp>

Comment: If you did want that shared set, you can just put one in a companion object and make your overridden `players` property point at it: https://pl.kotl.in/Z6m8LKjTp

Comment: “the docs say \[HashSet] requires less memory than a normal set”  — which docs? I can't think what ‘normal set’ might mean; `HashSet`'s probably the most commonly-used set.  There are certainly Set implementations which take more memory — Kotlin's default of `LinkedHashSet` takes a little more, and `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()` much more — but others take significantly less. In any case, it's usually more flexible and future-proof to simply refer to the `Set` or `MutableSet` interface where possible, to avoid unnecessary restrictions, and then specify the type of set only when creating it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you create two separate instances of `Supa`. You invoke `later()` on one of them and then print `players` of another one. Each `Supa()` creates a new instance.

You need to store `Supa` instance inside a variable and use it in both places:

```kotlin
val supa = Supa()
supa.later()
println(supa.players)
```

This isn't really specific to Kotlin. Your code would work the same in other languages as well.